# Error seen when adding data to new model due to possible id issue

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I am using Django and MongoDB.

I have two models that are very similar. I decided to make a second one as a "v2" for some testing before wiping out my original. After I created it and then started to test it I noticed that it was not getting a `id` field added to it automatically like the original model is.

Models:

```
# Old Model (works)
class Commands(models.Model):
    client_id = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=None)
    command_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    command_name = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=False, default='')
    command_status = models.CharField(max_length=32, default='')
    command_error = models.CharField(max_length=8, default = '0')
    command_response = models.TextField(default='')
    command_timestamp = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)

# New Model
class Command(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=False, default='')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=False, default='')
    error = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=False, default='')
    response = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=False, default='')
    timestamp = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=False, default='')
    client = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=False, default='')
    kind = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=False, default='')
```

Serializers

```
# Old Serializer (works)
class CommandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 
    class Meta:
        model = Commands
        fields = ('id',
                  'client_id',
                  'command_name',
                  'command_status',
                  'command_error',
                  'command_response',
                  'command_timestamp',
                  'command_id',
                  )

# New Serializer
class CommandSerializer2(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 
    class Meta:
        model = Command
        fields = ('id',
                  'name',
                  'status',
                  'error',
                  'response',
                  'timestamp',
                  'client',
                  'kind',
                  )
```

URLS

```
# Old URL
re_path(r'^api/addcommand$', views.add_command),

# New URL
path("test/add", views.CommandCreate.as_view())
```

Views

```
# Old View
@api_view(['POST'])
def add_command(request):
    command_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    command_serializer = CommandSerializer(data=command_data)
    if command_serializer.is_valid():
        command_serializer.save()
        return JsonResponse(command_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, safe=False)
    return JsonResponse(command_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

# New View
class CommandCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Command.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommandSerializer2
```

I have a script I use to test adding that looks like:

```
import requests

old_endpoint = "http://localhost:8000/api/addcommand"
old_data = {'client_id': 1, 'command_id': 'x', 'command_name': 'x',  'command_status': 'x', 'command_error': 'x', 'command_response': 'x', 'command_timestamp': 1, }

new_endpoint = "http://localhost:8000/test/add"
new_data = {'name': 'x', 'status': 'x', 'error': 'x', 'response': 'x', 'timestamp': 'x', 'client': 'x', 'kind': 'x'}

get_response = requests.post(endpoint, json=data)
print(get_response.content)
```

When running this against the `old_endpoint` it inserts without issue and `id` appears as a field in the database. If I run it against the `new_endpoint` I get a error that says:

`TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'ObjectId'`

If I change the model and serializer to the old one in the `CommandCreate` and run it, it works for the old model as it should. I cannot figure out why it would not work for the new model. I have also deleted both collections for `Command` and `Commands` and no change.